# How to add position to products in product listing comes from search results in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I am trying to add a position attribute in product object in
product listing which comes from search results.

Anybody have any idea how do achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing good.

You can do it by following the below steps:

1. Click on a category in the category tree to display the category related information.
2. Then, click on “Category Products” tab that will display the category products grid.
3. In the last column of product grid set/update the product position.
4. If you see no product listed in the “Category Products” tab, it means that the category has no products assigned to it. So click the “Reset Filter” button to list all products, now select the products first and then in the last column of the product grid set the product position.
5. Last, save the category.

Besides, The product position is a global attribute and there is a table with the relation between category id and product ids and also the position for that product in that category. The table is: catalog_category_product.

I hope that works for you.

Last you can also check for [Magento DevDoc](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/categories-custom-design.html) but its for version 2.

Comment: I want to get the position of the product from product list page , into a js file